Loading multiple JSON files from my local directory into Tabulator table
I am trying to load multiple JSON files from my local directory into Tabulator 6.2 table. I verified JSON files are correctly formatted. And that my Tabulator table fields match JSON file fields and my Tabulator table will load successful a single JSON file. I need to get multiple JSON files from my local SaDirectory to load into my table.
My SaDirectory contains these JSON formatted files:
123.JSON
124.JSON
125.JSON
I tried to load with this ajax code:
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
ajaxURL:"C:\Users\Desktop\SaDirectory" });
});

Also tried this Tabulator import code:
table.import("json", ".json")
I can load one JSON file, but cannot get tabulator to load all JSON files from
SaDirectory.
Please help. Thanks.

Instead of using ajaxURL, you can try fetching all the files after table is built and then loading them into your table as such:
table.on('tableBuilt', () => {
  const files = ['./123.json', './124.json', './125.json']

  const requests = files.map((file) => fetch(file))

  Promise.all(requests)
    .then((responses) => Promise.all(responses.map((res) => res.json())))
    .then((results) => {
      results.forEach((result) => {
        table.addData(result)
      })
    })
    .catch(console.error)
})

There may be other methods available to get the files depending on your setup/use case.
